# Rendering OpenGL in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, opengl, visualization

I try to create an WPF Application with an integrated OpenGL visualization.

I found [the sample project SharpGL](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3144/SharpGL-a-C-OpenGL-class-library) it helped me to integrate the opengl code into my wpf program.

now I just want to draw a rectangle which has the following attributes:

```
40 x coordinates = columns
48 y coordinates = rows
```

Each (x,y) coordinate has a value which I have defined in an `List<float>`.
The `List<float>` is dynamically, so it will change all the time. 
The goal is too show the values in real time in the drawed rectangle.

```
Like:
          y-coord
x coord   0  2  0  3  7  0  1  ..40
          4  5  3  0  6  0  5  ..40
          .  .
          .  .
          48 48
```

Unfortunately I fail already when I try to draw the rectangle.

```
 private void openGLControl_OpenGLDraw(object sender, OpenGLEventArgs args)
    {
        //  Get the OpenGL object.
        OpenGL gl = openGLControl.OpenGL;

        //  Clear the color and depth buffer.
        gl.Clear(OpenGL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //  Load the identity matrix.
        //gl.LoadIdentity();
        gl.PolygonMode(FaceMode.FrontAndBack, PolygonMode.Filled);
        gl.Color(0,0,0);
        //  Draw a coloured pyramid.
        gl.Begin(OpenGL.GL_QUADS);
        gl.Vertex(-1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.Color(200,1,1);
        gl.Vertex(-1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.Color(200, 1, 1);
        gl.Vertex(1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.Color(200, 1, 1);
        gl.Vertex(1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.Color(200, 1, 1);
        gl.End();

        //  Nudge the rotation.
        //rotation += 3.0f;
    }
```

My code shows just a black window.

How could I realize that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you forgot to call *gl.Flush()* or *gl.Finish()* at the end of your *openGLControl_OpenGLDraw()* method. Until you call any of these methods (or *gl.SwapBuffers()* in case of double buffering) every drawing method you call will only be buffered but not executed.